# How to set android view or viewgroup backdround transparent for showing wallpaper?

Tags: android

I know how to set an application or activity level theme to make layout show transparent, and show the content of wallpaper, but how to do it just for view or viewgroup?

there is a example from a WindowsPhone like launcher SquareHome on GooglePlay https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/lZ6xyEbkmWgmAMFCOMVvFDHLC0DoT-HwAT1WjL5JRmmeQIW0_5JHugh8XkuVMAbT7nY=w1366-h663-rw

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the activity transparent.
draw whatever you want to draw over the transparent activity.
By Default all the view are transparent if not then set the

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

Comment: Yes i know how to make an activity transparent, but i need a viewgroup background black and its child view transparent